# Output to stderr is instead going to stdout

Tags: linux, emacs, stdout, stderr, eshell

I'm facing a weird problem; whenever I run a command in `eshell` (wether it is a simple command, a complex application or a toy example) every output which should go towards `stderr` goes to `stdout` instead.

This is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cerr << "ERROR\n";
   std::cout << "OUTPUT\n";

}
```

I get the following:

```
~ $ ./a.out 2> /dev/null
ERROR
OUTPUT
```

Launching the same command with `shell`, `term` or an external terminal works as expected. Even launching either `dash`, `sh` or `bash` inside `eshell` and then launching the program works.

Is this an `eshell` bug? Could it be some wrong configuration from my side?
My emacs version is `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`

Thank you,
Nikolas

Comment: Seems like an eshell bug. Eshell's *info* has a section on redirection, but stderr isn't mentioned there at all.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Eshell documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Introduction):

> #### 1.2 What Eshell is not
>
> Eshell is not a replacement for system shells such as bash or zsh. Use Eshell when you want to move text between Emacs and external processes; if you only want to pipe output from one external process to another (and then another, and so on), use a system shell, because Emacs’s IO system is buffer oriented, not stream oriented, and is very inefficient at such tasks. If you want to write shell scripts in Eshell, don’t; either write an elisp library or use a system shell.
>
> Some things Eshell just doesn’t do well. It fills the niche between IELM and your system shell, where the peculiar use-cases lie, and it is less than ideal outside that niche.

That would be enough to scare me away from using it in favor of bash or zsh.